# Creating a scatter plot with multiple (>10) variables from repeated measures in SPSS

Tags: spss

Some **explaining facts** in the beginning:
I have got my data structured in SPSS in the following way.
I've got 20 variables (case_number, a_1, b_1, c_1, a_2, b_2, c_2, ....)
The variables are named in such a way because I took repeated measures (at different points of time, here named 1 and 2) with different devices (named a, b and c). All devices are supposed to measure the same.

**What I want to do** now is create a **scatter plot for all devices** and **all points of time**, e.g. I would like to have device a on the x-axis and devices b and c on the y-axis and then plot
(a_1, b_1)
(a_1, c_1)
(a_2, b_2)
(a_2, c_2) 
and so on.

I would like **all points that use device b** on the y-axis to have the same color (e.g. **green**), p**oints using device c** should have **another color** (e.g. red).
I do NOT want to use different colors for different points of time, so both (a_1, b_1) and (a_2, b_2) should be green.

Comment: I've voted to migrate this over to stackoverflow, because as stated it is just a "how do I do X in SPSS" type question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular example is easier to construct if you have the data in long format as opposed to wide format. Below is an example.

```
*Make some fake data.
SET SEED 10.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP ID = 1 TO 50.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
DATASET NAME Sim.
VECTOR a_(3).
VECTOR b_(3).
VECTOR c_(3).
DO REPEAT v = a_1 TO c_3.
  COMPUTE v = RV.NORMAL(0,1).
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.

*Reshape from wide to long.
VARSTOCASES 
  /MAKE a FROM a_1 TO a_3
  /MAKE b FROM b_1 TO b_3
  /MAKE c FROM c_1 TO c_3
  /INDEX Time.
FORMATS a b c Time (F2.0).

*Now make scatterplot.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=a b c
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: a=col(source(s), name("a"))
  DATA: b=col(source(s), name("b"))
  DATA: c=col(source(s), name("c"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("a"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("b and c"))
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*b), color.interior(color.green))
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*c), color.interior(color.red))
END GPL.
```

This produces the plot I believe you asked for:

[image]

In long format you have several other simple options as well, like constructing small multiples for each time period or using different symbols for each time period.

```
*Small multiple graphs.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=a b c Time
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: a=col(source(s), name("a"))
  DATA: b=col(source(s), name("b"))
  DATA: c=col(source(s), name("c"))
  DATA: Time=col(source(s), name("Time"), unit.category())
  COORD: rect(dim(1,2))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("a"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("b and c"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(3), opposite())
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*b*Time), color.interior(color.green))
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*c*Time), color.interior(color.red))
END GPL.

*Different shapes for different time periods.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=a b c Time ID
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: a=col(source(s), name("a"))
  DATA: b=col(source(s), name("b"))
  DATA: c=col(source(s), name("c"))
  DATA: Time=col(source(s), name("Time"), unit.category())
  DATA: ID=col(source(s), name("ID"), unit.category())
  COORD: rect(dim(1,2))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("a"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("b and c"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(3), opposite())
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*b), color.interior(color.green), shape(Time))
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*c), color.interior(color.red), shape(Time))
END GPL.
```

Another option is to draw the traces of each individual. In this sample because the data are quite disorderly they are not appropriate, but most time series data will show smoother trends. Here is an example small multiple of the traces for the first 5 observations in their own small multiples, for this example data. (See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/152132/1036) for some discussion on these diagrams and nice examples.)

```
*Path traces.
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF ID <= 5.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=a b c Time ID
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: a=col(source(s), name("a"))
  DATA: b=col(source(s), name("b"))
  DATA: c=col(source(s), name("c"))
  DATA: Time=col(source(s), name("Time"), unit.category())
  DATA: ID=col(source(s), name("ID"), unit.category())
  COORD: rect(dim(1,2), wrap())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("a"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("b and c"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(3), opposite())
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*b*ID), color.interior(color.green), shape(Time))
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*c*ID), color.interior(color.red), shape(Time))
  ELEMENT: path(position(a*b*ID))
  ELEMENT: path(position(a*c*ID))
END GPL.
EXECUTE.
```

---

The updated code in the comment meant to generate a legend works fine for me, with the exception of the inline template (which might conflict with my personal chart template). If you want to add a regression line to the plot see the `smooth.linear` function in the [GPL reference guide](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/22.0/en/client/Manuals/GPL_Reference_Guide_for_IBM_SPSS_Statistics.pdf).

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=a b c
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE INLINETEMPLATE=["<addFitline type='linear' target='pair'/>"]. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: a=col(source(s), name("a")) 
  DATA: b=col(source(s), name("b")) 
  DATA: c=col(source(s), name("c")) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("a")) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("b and c")) 
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), map(("b", color.green), ("c", color.blue))) 
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*b), color.interior("b")) 
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*c), color.interior("c")) 
END GPL.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your excellent help. I was wondering how to add a legend to the first graph (it's not working using the GUI - the legend can't be activated there).

Comment: @Ihkavs - For the first graph, you have to map aesthetics to make a legend. So instead of `color.interior(color.green)` you could do `color.interior("b")`. This will produce a legend for that point. You can then use `SCALE: cat(aesthetic....` to set the colors for specific categories.

Comment: I still got it wrong in some place, can't find the mistake though.  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE
     INLINETEMPLATE=["<addFitline type='linear' target='pair'/>"].
BEGIN GPL
 SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
 DATA: a=col(source(s), name("a"))
 DATA: b=col(source(s), name("b"))
 DATA: c=col(source(s), name("c"))
 GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("a"))
 GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("b and c"))
 SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), map(("b", color.green), ("c", color.blue)))
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*b), color.interior("b"))
  ELEMENT: point(position(a*c), color.interior("c"))
END GPL.

Comment: I've added that example @Ihkavs - it works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you @Andy W. It does work for me as well now. I didn't find a mistake though why it wasn't working before - all I got for hours was an internal translation error. Sorry about that.